# Scrolling is not perform in Listview in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that, I am adding listview in LinearLayout dynamically through code and set the EndlessAdapter into that, Data is shown correctly but we are unable to scroll from top to bottom in the list. I don't know why? please suggest me any solution regarding the same.

**Code:**

```
public void setValuesInCategoryChild(String url, final String filter, final String from, final String to) {
    if (isOnline()) {
        final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(ResearchList.this, "Research List       ", "Please wait...   ", true);
        final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // System.out.println("The id after Save:"+id.get(0).toString());
            // catagory.addAll(keyword_vector1);
            linear_Category_Child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            linear_Category_Child_Child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // tv_Child_Header.setText("Volvo");
            tv_CategoryChildHeader.setText(from);
            setHeaderImage(tv_CategoryChildHeader.getText().toString());
            System.out.println("The size of Cat Display names:" + coll.getDisplayNames().size());
            System.out.println("The size of Cat Images:" + coll.getImages().size());
            System.out.println("The size of Cat price:" + coll.getPrice().size());
            System.out.println("The size of Cat Year:" + coll.getYears().size());
            System.out.println("The size of Cat Rating:" + coll.getRating().size());
            System.out.println("The size of Cat Mpg:" + coll.getMpg().size());
            setHeaderImage(tv_CategoryChildHeader.getText().toString());
            if(coll.getDisplayNames().size()!=0) {
                lvCategory = new ListView(ResearchList.this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                lvCategory.setLayoutParams(params);

                // Adapter for MPG Search
                demoAdapterCat = new DemoAdapterCat();
                lvCategory.setAdapter(demoAdapterCat);
                layout_ResearchList_BrandList.addView(lvCategory);
                Utility.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lvCategory);
            }else {
                /*lvCategory.invalidate();
                lvCategory.setAdapter(null);*/
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(ResearchList.this);
                builder.setTitle("Attention!");
                builder.setMessage("No Data Available for the Particular Search.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });

                builder.create().show();
            }
            /*Utility util = new Utility();
            util.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lvCategory);*/
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    };
    final Thread checkUpdate = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                String sortEncode = URLEncoder.encode("mpg");
                String filterEncode = URLEncoder.encode(filter);
                String clientEncode = URLEncoder.encode("10030812");
                String fromEncode = URLEncoder.encode(from);
                String toEncode = URLEncoder.encode(to);
                String catUrl = "/v1/vehicles/get-make-models.json?sort=" + sortEncode + "&filter=" + filterEncode + "&client-id=" + clientEncode + "&from=" + fromEncode;
                genSig = new GetSignature(catUrl, "acura");
                try {
                    signature = genSig.getUrlFromString();
                } catch (InvalidKeyException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                // jsonString =
                // getJsonSring("http://api.highgearmedia.com/v1/vehicles/get-models.json?make=acura&client-id=10030812&signature=LWQbdAlJVxlXZ1VO2mfqAA==");
                // String signatureEncode =
                // URLEncoder.encode(signature);
                String urlEncode = URLEncoder.encode(catUrl + "&signature=" + signature);
                jsonString = getJsonSring("http://apibeta.highgearmedia.com" + catUrl + "&signature=" + signature);
                System.out.println("The json category:===>" + jsonString);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JsonParse json = new JsonParse(jsonString);
            json.parseCat();
            LIST_SIZE = coll.getDisplayNames().size();
            for (int i = 0; i <= BATCH_SIZE; i++) {
                // countriesSub.add(COUNTRIES[i]);
                countriesSubCat.add(coll.getDisplayNames().get(i));
                imagesSubCat.add(coll.getImages().get(i));
                YearSubCat1.add(coll.getYears().get(i));
                YearSubCat2.add(coll.getYears().get(i + 1));
                mpgSubCat1.add(coll.getMpg().get(i));
                mpgSubCat2.add(coll.getMpg().get(i + 1));
                priceSubCat1.add(coll.getPrice().get(i));
                priceSubCat2.add(coll.getPrice().get(i + 1));
                ratingSubCat1.add(coll.getRating().get(i));
                ratingSubCat2.add(coll.getRating().get(i + 1));
            }
            setLastOffset(BATCH_SIZE);
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    };
    checkUpdate.start();
} else {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(ResearchList.this);
    builder.setTitle("Attention!");
    builder.setMessage("Network Connection unavailable.");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
    builder.create().show();
}
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_ResearchListCategoryChild_Child"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_ResearchListCategoryChild_Child_HeaderBlock"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="@drawable/catagory_bar"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_ResearchListCategoryChild_Child_Header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Work in Progress"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginLeft="60dip"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_ResearchListCategory_ChildHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:src="@drawable/up_arrow" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/list_arrow_up" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_ResearchListCategoryChild_Child_Header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:background="@drawable/nav_bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Highest Rated"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="A-Z"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="Price"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:text="MPG"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

                <!--
                <RelativeLayout 
                    android:id="@+id/relative_down_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    >

                </RelativeLayout>

                -->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearArrowLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/Highly_rated"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/selector_arrow"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/AZ_arrow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/selector_arrow"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/Price_arrow"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/selector_arrow"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/MPG"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/selector_arrow"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="12dip" android:background="#ffffff" android:id="@+id/layout_ResearchList_BrandList">
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
```

**DemoAdapterCat:**

```
class DemoAdapterCat extends EndlessAdapter {
        ImageLoader image = new ImageLoader(ResearchList.this);
        private RotateAnimation rotate = null;
        ArrayList<String> tempListNamesCat = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListImagesCat = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListYearCat1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListYearCat2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListmpgCat1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListmpgCat2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListpriceCat1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListpriceCat2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListRatingCat1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> tempListRatingCat2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        DemoAdapterCat() {
            super(new CategoryListLazyAdapter(ResearchList.this,
                    countriesSubCat, imagesSubCat, YearSubCat1, YearSubCat2,
                    mpgSubCat1, mpgSubCat2, priceSubCat1, priceSubCat2,
                    ratingSubCat1, ratingSubCat2));
            /*Utility util = new Utility();
            util.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lvCategory);*/
            rotate = new RotateAnimation(0f, 360f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            rotate.setDuration(600);
            rotate.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
            rotate.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        }

        /*
         * @Override public int getCount() { return
         * brandList.getDisplayNames().size(); //return count+=10; }
         */
        @Override
        protected View getPendingView(ViewGroup parent) {
            row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.categorylist, null);

            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_Name);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_MPG1);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_MPG2);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_Price1);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_Price2);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_Rating1);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_Rating2);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_Year1);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.tv_CategoryItem_Year2);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.linear_CategoryList_itemlayer1);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.linear_CategoryList_itemlayer2);
            child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            /*
             * child = row.findViewById(R.id.img_CategoryItem);
             * child.setVisibility(View.GONE); child =
             * row.findViewById(R.id.img_CategoryItem_Arrow);
             * child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             */

            /*
             * child = row.findViewById(R.id.linear_main_MPG);
             * child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             */
            child = row.findViewById(R.id.throbber);
            child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            child.startAnimation(rotate);

            return (row);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean cacheInBackground() {
            //count += 10;
            SystemClock.sleep(100000);
            tempListNamesCat.clear();
            tempListImagesCat.clear();
            tempListmpgCat1.clear();
            tempListmpgCat2.clear();
            tempListpriceCat1.clear();
            tempListpriceCat2.clear();
            tempListYearCat1.clear();
            tempListYearCat2.clear();
            tempListRatingCat1.clear();
            tempListRatingCat2.clear();
//          countriesSubCat.clear();
//          imagesSubCat.clear();
//          YearSubCat1.clear();
//          YearSubCat2.clear();
//          mpgSubCat1.clear();
//          mpgSubCat2.clear();
//          priceSubCat1.clear();
//          priceSubCat2.clear();
//          ratingSubCat1.clear();
//          ratingSubCat2.clear();

            int lastOffset = getLastOffset();
            if (lastOffset < LIST_SIZE) {
                int limit = lastOffset + BATCH_SIZE;
                for (int i = (lastOffset + 1); (i <= limit && i < LIST_SIZE); i++) {
                    tempListNamesCat.add(coll.getDisplayNames().get(i));
                    tempListImagesCat.add(coll.getImages().get(i));
                    tempListmpgCat1.add(coll.getMpg().get(i));
                    tempListmpgCat2.add(coll.getMpg().get(i + 1));
                    tempListpriceCat1.add(coll.getPrice().get(i));
                    tempListpriceCat2.add(coll.getPrice().get(i + 1));
                    tempListRatingCat1.add(coll.getRating().get(i));
                    tempListRatingCat2.add(coll.getRating().get(i + 1));
                    tempListYearCat1.add(coll.getYears().get(i));
                    tempListYearCat2.add(coll.getYears().get(i + 1));
                }

                setLastOffset(limit);

                if (limit < LIST_SIZE) {
                    // return true;
                    return (getWrappedAdapter().getCount() < coll
                            .getDisplayNames().size());
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void appendCachedData() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            // Activity activity = this;
            // ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapterNew =
            // (ArrayAdapter<String>)getWrappedAdapter();
            CategoryListLazyAdapter arrAdapterNewCategory = (CategoryListLazyAdapter) getWrappedAdapter();
            // int listLen = tempList.size();
            // int listLen = tempListNames.size();
            countriesSubCat.addAll(tempListNamesCat);
            imagesSubCat.addAll(tempListImagesCat);
            mpgSubCat1.addAll(tempListmpgCat1);
            mpgSubCat2.addAll(tempListmpgCat2);
            priceSubCat1.addAll(tempListpriceCat1);
            priceSubCat2.addAll(tempListpriceCat2);
            ratingSubCat1.addAll(tempListRatingCat1);
            ratingSubCat2.addAll(tempListRatingCat2);
            YearSubCat1.addAll(tempListYearCat1);
            YearSubCat2.addAll(tempListYearCat2);
            arrAdapterNewCategory.notifyDataSetChanged();
            /*Utility util = new Utility();
            util.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(lvCategory);*/
            /*
             * for(int i=0; i<listLen; i++){ //
             * arrAdapterNew.add(tempList.get(i)); }
             */
        }
    }
```

Thanks in adavance.

Comment: am I missing something? If you are using an EndlessAdapter then there will be no "bottom" of the list, it should scroll basically forever without hitting the bottom.

Comment: Yes exactly, but I unable to scroll the list. from top to bottom in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `ScrollView` in the xml file.